How do I write tests to compare my .NET WebAPI endpoint results with legacy endpoints running on http://localhost
I've tried setting up this test class
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

namespace ApiComparisonTests
{
    public class ApiComparisonFixture : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>>
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;
        private readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;

        public ApiComparisonFixture(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> factory, ITestOutputHelper output)
        {
            _factory = factory;
            _httpClient = _factory.CreateClientWithCustomBaseAddress();
            _output = output;

            _output.WriteLine($"Base Address: {_httpClient.BaseAddress}");
        }

        [Theory]
        [InlineData(@"http://localhost/", "some stuff", "some more stuff")]
        public async Task FirstTest(string oldApiBaseUrl, string someStuff, string someMoreStuff)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> formData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            formData["someStuff"] = someStuff;
            formData["someMoreStuff"] = someMoreStuff;

            string endpoint = "Some/Path/EndpointName";

            // Get the responses
            var newApiResponse = await GetApiResponseAsync("", endpoint, formData, true);
            var oldApiResponse = await GetApiResponseAsync(oldApiBaseUrl, endpoint, formData, true);

            oldApiResponse.Remove("PropertyOnlyInOldApi");
            newApiResponse.Remove("PropertyOnlyInNewApi");

            bool areEqual = JsonComparer.JTokenDeepEqualsIgnoreOrder(oldApiResponse, newApiResponse);

            Assert.True(areEqual);
        }

        private async Task<JObject> GetApiResponseAsync(string url, string endpoint, Dictionary<string, string> formData, bool isPost)
        {
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            foreach (var item in formData)
            {
                content.Add(new StringContent(item.Value), item.Key);
            }

            if (isPost)
            {
                var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(@$"{url}{endpoint}", content);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JObject.Parse(responseBody);
            }
            else
            {
                var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{url}/{endpoint}");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JObject.Parse(responseBody);
            }
        }

    }
}

and this CustomWebApplicationFactory class
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace ApiComparisonTests
{
    public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> : WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> where TEntryPoint : class
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.UseTestServer();

            builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                var inMemorySettings = new Dictionary<string, string?>
                {
                    { "TestServerBaseUrl", "http://localhost:6000" }
                };

                config.AddInMemoryCollection(inMemorySettings);
            });
        }

        public HttpClient CreateClientWithCustomBaseAddress()
        {
            var client = CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:6000")
            });
            return client;
        }
    }
}

However, both newApiResponse and oldApiResponse get populated with the result from the new api. I assume that's because this way of setting up the CustomWebApplicationFactory overrides http://localhost, although I don't really understand why given that I'm specifying a port in the baseUrl. Is there some way to host my api for the test, while still being able to reach the other api that is running on http://localhost? (I can't move it right now, for reasons beyond the scope of this post).
